# How to authorize my Android App to upload data to Google BigQuery in a background task?

Tags: android, google-bigquery

I want to upload data to Google BigQuery from my Android App in a background task. I think, I could do an [insert job](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert) with the Java library. But the [authorization page](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization#installed-applications) says:

> During the authorization flow, the application will redirect the user to a Google-hosted webpage to request access to the BigQuery API.

But this isn't what I want. I want to upload the data in the background. And I don't want to authorize the Android app user, I want to authorize the app.

It is possible to use Google BigQuery to store my big data collected by my Android app? And how do I have to authorize my app against Google?

I hope, you understand my problem and could give me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

*Re: "It is possible to use Google BigQuery to store my big data collected by my Android app?"*

Yes. BigQuery can load quite a lot of data at a time (up to 1 Tb), and it is possible to run [up to 10,000 load jobs per project](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/quota-policy#import), but essentially, loading data into BigQuery is a batch process. Therefore:

**Method 1:**
Create a web-based application to collect data from your Android app via a RESTful API. Then, at intervals (daily? hourly?), move newly collected data into Google Cloud Storage. Finally, kick off a BigQuery ingestion job to ingest the recently collected data into BigQuery from Google Cloud Storage.

One way to build the first part is to use the App Engine Datastore to collect data from your Android application. It's possible to use the [new Datastore Admin backup to BigQuery feature](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/UuAJtwj8la8) to load your collected data into BigQuery for analysis.

**Method 2:**
You can use Android's AccountManager class ([see tutorial here](http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html)) to authorize access to the BigQuery API, and then use a direct POST request ([using a multi-part mime request](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/import#localimport)) to add data to a BigQuery table. This flow requires the Android app user to authorize access to the BigQuery API when using the app.

Comment: I've tried to import Datastore Admin backup via Cloud Storage. Do I actually fill out the form you have linked? Both the BigQuery Browser Tool and the bq Command-Line Tool supports importing Datastore Backups from Cloud Storage.

I've tried to import my Datastore Backup from Cloud Storage. But I get always the following error:

`Unable to read source URI: gs://[bucket]/datastore_backup_datastore_backup_2012_1
0_19_-158292135412116FADBAB-output-0`

I can download the file with the Cloud Storage tool. BigQuery and Cloud Storage are in the same project as shown in the API Console.

Comment: I would suggest filling out the Trusted Tester form for now,  there will be additional documentation available when you sign up: https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dHdpeXlmRlZCNWlYSE9BcE5jc2NYOUE6MQ

Comment: @Cornelius, were you able to figure out a solution for this? I'm trying to do exactly this for my app too but cannot figure out how.

Comment: @FebianShah: No, unfortunately not. I've done it differently without BigQuery. But if you find a solution feel free to post it here.