# Error 200 (job canceled) when streaming data from Android to BigQuery

Tags: android, google-bigquery

I've been trying to build some functionality into my app too allow user-generated data (EEG recordings) to be sent to a central BigQuery database.

I've never done any networking code in Java before, so I shied away from doing the POST or REST-based strategies recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785752/how-to-authorize-my-android-app-to-upload-data-to-google-bigquery-in-a-backgroun). The [BigQuery Java client library](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.26.0/index.html) seemed to be exactly what I needed, though I was completely confused why it wouldn't officially support Android.

Still, I came across this [example Android app](https://github.com/googlecloud-android/googlecloud-bigquery-android) (from Google no less) that promised to do exactly what I wanted with the BigQuery Client library. I incorporated it into my app as follows:

```
// .... in an AsyncTask
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String CSV_CONTENT = params[0];
    try {
        AssetManager am = MainApplication.getInstance().getAssets();
        InputStream isCredentialsFile = am.open(CREDENTIALS_FILE);
        BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.builder()
                .authCredentials(AuthCredentials.createForJson(isCredentialsFile))
                .projectId( PROJECT_ID )
                .build().service();

        TableId tableId = TableId.of(DATASET,TABLE);
        Table table = bigquery.getTable(tableId);

        int num = 0;
        Log.d("Main", "Sending CSV: ");
        WriteChannelConfiguration configuration = WriteChannelConfiguration.builder(tableId)
                .formatOptions(FormatOptions.csv())
                .build();
        try (WriteChannel channel = bigquery.writer(configuration)) {
            num = channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(CSV_CONTENT.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Main", e.toString());
        }
        Log.d("Main", "Loading " + Integer.toString(num) + " bytes into table " + tableId);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Main", "Exception: " + e.toString());
    }

    return "Done";
}
```

This runs without any errors and fires off an API call that is detected by Google Cloud Storage. However, it returns error 200 (job was cancelled) every time. I don't understand how this could be since I'm not doing anything in the code to cancel the request and I don't see how the async task I put the call in could be cancelled.

Was this just a bad example app I copied and a bad usage of the BigQuery Client? If so, what's the best way to send data to BigQuery from Android?

Comment: Don't you need to flush and/or close the channel? I don't know anything about this example, but I'm confused about why it uses CSV (the streaming API is JSON-based). Depending on how much data you are logging, it may be worth looking into Firebase, which you can connect to BigQuery for analytics.

Comment: Actually, I changed the example to use CSV instead of JSON. There was a CSV option built into the FormatOptions so I expected it wouldn't cause a problem. Perhaps that's the reason why it's failing. I'll try JSON